# JQuery .children() not returning dynamically added elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, dynamically-generated

I am integrating a live chat functionality and I am trying to use a JQuery statement to get the chat session ID from a div ID that is not created until a chat is started. (It is dynamically added to the page.) Of course logically, I am making sure that I don't try to select the element until after a chat has started and it exists. Here is the relevant HTML structure and the line of code that I am using:

HTML:

```
<!--These do not exist until a chat is started-->
    <div class="customer_inner_widget">
        <div id="chat-session-5748220" style="height:100%;">
```

JQuery:

```
$(".customer_inner_widget").children().first().attr("id").split("-")[2]
```

---

The strangest thing is that under normal circumstances either when I run it in my script upon closing the chat OR I run it in Google Chrome Developer Tools Console AFTER a chat has started, it does not work:

```
Output:
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
        at <anonymous>:1:58
```

...but If I simply right click on the chat window on my page and select "inspect", then run the same line of code in the console... it works:

```
Output:
    "5748220"
```

How does just inspecting the HTML wilth Chrome suddenly cause it to work...? How can I perform this hidden magic in my script?

Comment: Your ID doesn't have closing double quotes, jQuery used in that context doesn't care when the element is created

Comment: My bad, the HTML is correct I just typed it out manually here because I couldnt figure out how to copy just one line in chrome

Comment: It is very difficult to know WHEN you are running your jquery code and you are not providing any context were this this code is being run. If you can create a small example that illustrates your issue (I know, it might be difficult but you can hard code some things) that will be highly useful to get a very good response.

Comment: I apologize I thought I made it clear. I am following these steps: 1)Load Page 2)Start Chat (The divs above now exist) 3)Run the line of JQuery in Chrome Developer Tools Console. (Doesn't Work) 4)Right Click Chat on my page and select "Inspect", this shows the HTML structure. 6)Execute same line of JQuery and it finally works for some reason.

Comment: Running it in the console works because you are running the jQuery AFTER the dynamic elements have been added to the DOM. When are you calling that line of jQuery? It would be better to see the codeblock over snippets.

Comment: In my script it is attached to an event listener that triggers when the chat's close button is clicked. But even when I run it in Chrome AFTER the elements exist, it still doesn't work until I inspect the HTML for some reason.

Comment: I think the fact that the error occurs at 'split' and not 'attr' indicates that the first child was found and returned successfully, but attr('id') returned undefined. Have you tried using prop('id') instead?

Comment: Tried prop, no luck. I've confirmed the children are in fact missing until I inspect with: $(".customer_inner_widget").children().length which returns 0 before I inspect the HTML, but returns 4 afterwards.

Comment: hmm. this is just a guess. i don't think it's related to the `inspect element` but to the right click event that triggers the adding of the children. but it's just a blind guess

Comment: Tried just right-clicking, still doesn't work. I have to actually click "Inspect" and then it works. From the research I've done, apparently Inspecting triggers a re-sizing of the page which I guess causes JQuery to update its knowledge of the DOM since ya know thats what JQuery does for responsive pages and whatnot, but I don't understand how I can trigger this "refresh" with code...

Comment: Nevermind it still doesn't work if I just resize the window myself, nothing works at all except inspecting the HTML I don't get how thats the only way to make it work this is making no sense to me

Answer (score 0):

So the issue seems to have something to do with the fact that the child I am trying to access is located within an iFrame and apparently you cannot access external dynamically added content within an iFrame. I guess that JQuery just becomes aware of what is inside after inspecting since it is being forced to discover the elements.